# org.restlet.Context timeout value

Tags: restlet

When org.restlet.Context is using Apache HttpClient to make the connection, how do I specify the timeout period the client should wait for the server to respond.  Here is what I have so far

```
    final Context context = new Context();
    context.getParameters().add("socketTimeout", "10000");
    context.getParameters().add("", "10000"); //?? connectionTimeout

    ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(context, ss.getUrl());
```

Is there documentation for the possible parameter values and their meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, all supported parameters for the HttpClient extension are described in this page:
http://www.restlet.org/documentation/snapshot/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/httpclient/HttpClientHelper.html

In your case, it seems that the `idleTimeout` parameter should bother.